# How can I remove this script starting in the background and messing up with PowerShell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, anaconda, startup

A while back when starting to learn Python I installed Python, Anaconda and a code editor. I remember that I was having problems making all of that work properly and I ended up using a hack I found so that my code editor could always run Python using Anaconda. I may have added a script to do that but I don't remember it well.

Now I don't use Anaconda anymore, I deleted the software, and when I use the PowerShell it always starts with an error because of this.

My question is, how can I get rid of this? I already removed all mentions of Anaconda in my path (or at least I tried to).

Here is the error I get:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\<MyName>\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\<MyName>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\<MyName>\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "h ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\<MyName>\...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Tom , unfortunately I only have "Import-Module posh-git" in my Powershell profile.

Comment: As you added your comment to your question and not my answer I never got notified. The exact location of the issue is line 4 in profile.ps1 as the error indicates: At C:\Users\<MyName>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4    what is that line?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably something in your Powershell profile file.
Open it with notepad and remove any unwanted items:

```
notepad $profile
```